# build succeed but exe close immediataly

Tags: python-3.x, build, exe, executable, pyinstaller

I made a script and I want to turn it executabel, the I used bdist_msi, but it build without error and crash when I run the exe.

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\Documents\Projetos\Trello api\Source\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6> .\teste.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
module.run()
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "teste.py", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\trello\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from trello.trelloclient import *
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\trello\trelloclient.py", line 4, in <module>
import requests
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
import urllib3
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
from .packages.six.moves import queue
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
result = self._resolve()
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
File "C:\Users\Guilherme Mendes\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\virtualconda\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'queue'
```

setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

executables = [
        Executable("teste.py", base=base)
]

buildOptions = dict(
        packages = ['xlsxwriter', 'iso8601', 'datetime', 'smtplib', 'time', 'os', 'trello', 'email.message'],
        includes = [],
        include_files = ['Parametros.txt', 'Base de Dados.xlsx', 'Cronograma de Servicos.xlsm'],
        excludes = []
)

setup(
    name = "Painel de Serviços",
    version = "2.0",
    description = "Painel de Exibição de agendamentos realizados no Trello",
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
 )
```

I've tried other tools like py2exe and pyinstaller, but occurs same thing.

Comment: The Queue module was renamed to queue in Python3. But in both Python versions, it is included in the Python Standard Library. So, I don't think this error would be caused by the module actually being missing. Are you using Python2? If so, a module you are using may be trying to 'import queue' when the module is named 'Queue' in Python2. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.5.

Comment: I've tried "from urllib3.connectionpool.packages.six.moves import queue" but raise an error saying urllib3.connectionpool is not a lib.

Comment: Disregard my last comment--I may delete it. Six is a python package that is meant for handling compatibility issues between Python versions. So, for me to suggest the error might be caused by using the wrong package name is not relevant. There must be a problem with how cx_Freeze is finding the queue module. Did you try including 'queue' in the packages list in your setup.py file? I can also help you build this using Pyinstaller if cx_Freeze proves too troublesome.

Comment: Great, @coltoneakins! I really would like know how to do this using Pyinstaller. This is not the first time that cx_freeze delays my developings.

Comment: I used pyinstaller --onefile <my_script_name>.py and worked good. So, I added the external files to dist and compressed him. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, awesome! If you run into further ImportErrors and ModuleNotFoundErrors, let me know. I have used Pyinstaller many times. Pyinstaller is also great because it has hooks for pretty much all major Python libraries--which makes it easy to include them without a fuss. But, it sounds like you got it all figured out.